# How do I fix two issues one being my bubbles being different sizes and not using the whole screen?

Tags: swiftui, visionos

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI project and facing an issue with the FlowModeColumnView. I have a FlowModeView with multiple columns, and I want each column to use the full horizontal space of the screen.

I've tried different approaches, including using GeometryReader and Spacer, but the content is still displayed in a vertical line rather than filling the entire horizontal space.

Here's a simplified version of my code

FlowModeColumnView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FlowModeColumnView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ColumnsViewModel
    var column: ColumnsViewModel.Column
    let maxBubbleWidth: CGFloat // Pass maxBubbleWidth as a parameter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Display the selected column's content
            // Adjust the sections based on your needs
            Menu {
                ForEach(viewModel.columns.filter { $0.name != column.name }, id: .self.name) { otherColumn in
                    Button(otherColumn.name) {
                        viewModel.swapColumnNames(currentName: column.name, newName: otherColumn.name)
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text(column.name)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding()
            }

            ScrollView { // Wrap the content in a ScrollView
                VStack {
                    if column.name == "Company" {
                        WeeklyCustomersSection(maxBubbleWidth: maxBubbleWidth)
                            .frame(maxWidth: maxBubbleWidth)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                        ReplyColumnView(maxBubbleWidth: maxBubbleWidth)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                        NewlyCreatedSection(maxBubbleWidth: maxBubbleWidth)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                        // Add more sections as needed
                    } else if column.name == "Sales" {
                        SalesLineChartView()
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                        SalesRevenueToday(maxBubbleWidth: maxBubbleWidth)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                        SalesCallToday(maxBubbleWidth: maxBubbleWidth)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                    } else if column.name == "Marketing" {
                        ClientsDonutChart() // Adding the donut chart
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                        ClientCallsTodaySection(maxBubbleWidth: maxBubbleWidth)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                        ClientSalesTodaySection(maxBubbleWidth: maxBubbleWidth)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                        OpenSalesTodaySection(maxBubbleWidth: maxBubbleWidth)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow wrapping
                    } else {
                        // Handle other column types
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Set the ScrollView to take the maximum available width

            Spacer() // Use Spacer to fill the remaining space horizontally
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

If I'm missing any code you want to see please let me know to help me fix an issue to this mystery. I have my ContentView if that's needed I can post it as well.

I tried using Geometry, I tried the stacks but nothing happened. It still has issues but my columnview which is the other button in my submenu works perfectly fine.

[image: applevision screenshot]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkBtP.jpg
is the printscreen for some reason i cant show it

Comment: Please include a [mre]